# Ambiguity error - varargs and parameter with same type

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I want to instanciate a given class with the following two constructors:

```
public Foo(File jarFile, String... args)
public Foo(File jarFile, String className, String... args)
```

I call the first constructor like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(jarFile, "arg-val-1", "arg-val-2");
```

This gives an compiler error "reference to PactProgram is ambiguous", which makes sense.

Is there any way to force using one of the constructors? I cannot change the interface.

Calling either of the constructors would be fine for me. Passing only the jar-file works fine, but I need to pass the arguments.

I have Oracle Java 1.6.0_38 running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since varargs are equivalent to arrays, you can do like this if you want to use the first one:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(jarFile, new String[]{"arg-val-1", "arg-val-2"});
```

For the second one, use:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(jarFile, "arg-val-1", new String[]{"arg-val-2"});
```

Comment: Thank's - this fixed it!
I like the explanation of zibi: "Varargs are equivalent to arrays..."

Answer (score 2):

To some extend... varargs are equivalent to arrays, so you can use the following:

```
Foo(file, new String[] { "string" });
Foo(file, "string", new String[] { "string" });
```